# Como puedo conectar mi front(localhost) con mi back en (localhost)

Tags: nodejs, angular, postgresql, webservice

El caso es el siguiente, poseo un front hecho en angular y ya se logro realizar el la conexion entre el back con la base de datos, todo esto de manera local... el problema es el siguiente, cuando trato de obtener informacion del back desde mi front con un servicio usando el protocolo http de angular, me es imposible obtener informacion del localhost, no obstante lo puedo obtener de un back end virtual.

La porcion de codigo que anexos es parte del servicio del, front..

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  uri = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

  }

  getUser(userId) {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+userId)
    
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')

  }

  getPuppies() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/puppies/')

  }
```

de esta linea por ejemplo>
return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')

puedo obtener datos sin problema

pero de esta 
 getPuppies() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/puppies/')

}
no logro obtener informacion alguna...

ya el nodejs esta sincronizado con la base de datos entiendase que al acceder desde el navegador del localhost:3000 obtengo el json de la base de datos creada en postgres... alguien tiene alguna propuesta?

Comment: La consola del navegador o la de NodeJs te da algun error?

Comment: Con que esta hecho tu backend?, Lo más seguro es que es un error de cors. Tal vez si podemos ver el código de backend lo podamos solucionar.

Answer (score 1):

Para habilitar de manera general las cabeceras necesarias para el cors, dentro de node existe la libreria [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
npm i cors
```

Dentro de proyecto, suponiendo que usas express. debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

//... tus configuraciones
app.use(cors())

//...
app.listen(5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser un problema de CORS necesitas que tu servidor BackEnd genere las 'cabeceras' correspondientes del tipo: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'.

Esto es para que las peticiones realizadas desde Javascript puedan tener acceso (permiso) de recibir el json.

En este [enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) puedes encontrar información de que es CORS y por que lo necesitas.

Comment: el problema es ese, q no tengo ni idea, de como modificar el cors para q me permita dicho acceso

Comment: @JesusAlfredo intenta con POSTMAN...